# Android Studio | Google Maps Api v2 | How to animate Marker?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I am currently trying to animate an Marker.
I am trying to change it's Icon so that it looks like its a walking figure.

This is the thread which should deal with it:

```
package com.example.?;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class MarkerAnimationThread extends Thread {

    Marker currentLocationMarker;
    GameMap map;
    int counter=0;
    MarkerAnimationThread thread = this;
    public MarkerAnimationThread(Marker currentLocationMarker, GameMap map) {
        this.currentLocationMarker = currentLocationMarker;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public final int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter=counter;
    }
    public Thread getThread() {
        return thread;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (true) {
                map.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        switch (getCounter()) {
                            case 0: currentLocationMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.figure_1)); setCounter(getCounter()+1); break;
                            case 1: currentLocationMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.figure_2)); setCounter(getCounter()+1); break;
                            case 2: currentLocationMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.figure_3)); setCounter(getCounter()+1); break;
                            case 3: currentLocationMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.figure_4)); setCounter(0); break;
                            default: currentLocationMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.figure_1)); break;
                        }
                        try {
                            getThread().wait(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is causing following error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
> ```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you use a `Handler` to do this?

Comment: Not quite sure :D